# Is this a PHP function?

Tags: php, syntax

I saw this in a facebook leaked code...

```
$disabled_warning = ((IS_DEV_SITE || IS_QA_SITE) && is_disabled_user($user));
```

now unless I am reading it wrong then it is saying that **(($var)** can be used as a function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's just setting the value to true or false.

It would be equivalent to this:

```
if((IS_DEV_SITE || IS_QA_SITE) && is_disabled_user($user))
  $disabled_warning = true;
else
  $disabled_warning = false;
```

Comment: Ahh I see now not sure why I didn't notice the ending ), thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

This may be naive but $disabled_warning is just storing the Boolean result of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

anyway variable functions look something like normal functions except with a dollar sign in front in PHP.

```
function foo($s){
  echo $s;
}

$bar = 'foo';

$bar('Cool');
```